# Efficient way to persist data to table inside a java iteration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to create a data insertion logic which will insert records to a table using JPA persistence mechanisms. This insertion logic is inside a java iteration. The total iteration count is greater than 10,000. I have used Java 8 in my application and the transaction logic is implemented through spring JPA integration. If anyone suggests best practice for improving the performance of this looping mechanism.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use batching simply. Show some code and attempt for more concrete answer.

Comment: You could use [Fastnate](http://fastnate.org/) which was written for loading thousands of JPA entities in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look over your items, create batches of say 500 or really whatever works for you, insert that subset.

```
int batchSize = 500;
List<Item> items = new ArrayList(batchSize);
for (Item item : asd) {
    items.add(item);
    if (items.size() >= batchSize) {
        //persist
    }
}
```